# lo_export does not exist in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, export, blob

I am logged in as the postgres user and am trying to export a blob from a Postgresql 9.3 database as using this query:

```
select lo_export(imgs.rast, '/tmp/img.tif') from imgs where rid = 1;
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function lo_export(bytea, unknown) does not exist
```

Do I need to install the lo_export function?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a function, which is used to export a large object, which is something different than a blob (`bytea` column type in Postgres).

There's no library function to export `bytea` to a file. You just use in your client program something like (Python example):

```
cursor = conn.execute("select rast from img were rid=%(rid)s", {"rid":1})
result = cursor.fetchone()
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb", suffix=".tif", delete=False) as f:
  f.write(result[0])
  result_filename = f.name
```

Please remember that this reads the whole data to memory multiple times, so if the data can be fairly large you can prefer to read it in chunks using `substring(rast from %(chunk_start)s for %(chunk_size)s)`. And ensure that the column is saved externally using `set storage external`.